# How to delete all documents except one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I use `express` with `mongodb` & `mongoose` stack and I literally don't know how to query the database

How can I remove all documents inside a collection except one by criteria?

Let me show what I mean

I have a collection with documents.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    subDocument: {
      id: 'a'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    subDocument: {
      id: 'b'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    subDocument: {
      id: 'c'
    }
  },
]
```

Each of these documents has own single sub-document. I want to remove all documents (on the first level) which does not meet the criteria in the sub-document.

If `subDocument.id` is not equal `'b'` remove document.

I would expect such result

```
[
  {
    id: 2,
    subDocument: {
      id: 'b'
    }
  },
]
```

P.S.
I can't find any good examples in mongoose documentation. Could you please provide me an example or share a resource where I can find such information

Big thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mongoose you can use [Model.remove](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.remove) and pass filter as parameter:

```
Model.remove({ 'subdocument.id': { $ne: 'b' } })
```

Edit: method `Model.remove` has been deprecated and it is recommended to use [Model.deleteMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany) instead:

```
Model.deleteMany({ 'subdocument.id': { $ne: 'b' } })
```

Comment: Hi, this answer was useful for me but seems like `Model.remove()` has been deprecated, we can use `Model.deleteMany()` instead: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.deleteMany